# Language(saved in cookie), specific navigation

Tags: perl, apache, .htaccess, cookies, setenv

I am not a master of *Apache/.htaccess*.

For a URL: `base-url/destination/`, I need to show the page in that language which saved in the cookie. If no language us saved in the cookie or if the cookie is not present, I need to show the page same as that of browser's language.

Now, in order to achieve this, I wrote rules in `.htaccess` file as:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /destination/$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} language_uiAAA(\w{3}).*?BBB
RewriteRule ^(.*)\$ $httpbase/%1/destination.html
```

This properly shows the page in the language saved in the cookie.

But, I've been asked to write rules using `SetEnvIf, SetEnvIfNoCase or prefer-language`.

Hence, I googled and wrote these rules:

```
SetEnvIf ^Cookie$ "(.+)" HTTP_MY_COOKIE=$1
SetEnvIf HTTP_MY_COOKIE ".+language_uiAAA(.+?)BBB.+" saved_language=$1
SetEnvIf saved_language "^(.+)$" prefer-language=$1
```

But,these rules aren't working. Please help.

**OR**

Please suggest a better way.

Comment: Why did you tag this "perl"?

Comment: I've used Perl to write this `.htaccess` file. I thought, great Perl Monks may have an answer to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voila!

Done!!

Here is the code:

```
SetEnvIf ^Cookie$ "(.+)" HTTP_MY_COOKIE=$1
SetEnvIf HTTP_MY_COOKIE ".+language_uiAAA(.+?)BBB.+" saved_language=$1
SetEnvIf saved_language "^(\w{2}).+$" prefer-language=$1
SetEnvIf REDIRECT_prefer-language (.+) prefer-language=$1
```